# Google Apps Script - Finding a match in two columns

Tags: google-apps-script

[Here is an example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mhXtal2H_n3qU0PiFyoaDlLAKUXdV7rozK97maa_zR0/edit#gid=0) of what I am working with.
This is the code I have written so far:

```
function autoAudit() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sA = ss.getSheetByName('Asset Audit Import');
    var sM = ss.getSheetByName('Master List');

    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10) {
        dd = '0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10) {
        mm = '0'+mm
    } 
    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

    var dateRange = sM.getRange('C2:C');
    var locRange = sM.getRange('B2:B');
    var tagRange = sM.getRange('A2:A');
    var dateValues = dateRange.getValues();
    var locValues = locRange.getValues();
    var tagValues = tagRange.getValues();

    var audit1Loc = sA.getRange('A2').getValue();//audit1Loc is just one value not an array of values
    var audit1Phone = sA.getRange('B2:B20');
    for(var i=0;i < audit1Loc.length;i++){
        if(audit1Loc[i]===locValues[i]){
            for(var j=0;j < audit1Phone.length;j++){
                if(audit1Phone[j]===tagValues[j]){
                    dateRange[i].setValue(today);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

What I am hoping to accomplish is to have new data import into the Asset Audit Import tab each day. At which point the script will run to do the following:

Set the Last Date Checked column in the Master List tab to 'today' if there is a match for the tag # and location in Asset Audit Import.

Sorry if this a little confusing, I am more than willing to provide further clarification.

I attempted to use for loops, mostly cause this is what I "somewhat" know, but I feel like I am either very close or terribly far away.

I was unable to find any questions that were similar enough to gain from, but please feel free to point me to additional reading.

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: `audit1Loc` is only a value, not a range, are you sure that's what you want to loop on?

Comment: That is a great a point. Let me rework. Thank you.

Comment: What 2 columns do you want to match?

Comment: I need to look for a match of Tag # (col A in Master List tab and col B in Asset Audit Import tab) AND that the Location (col B in Master List tab and col A in Asset Audit Import tab) match.

Comment: And if you find a match what do you want to do?

Comment: If a match is found I would to change the value of col C for that row in the Master List tab to today's date.